# eslint --fix not working when running by npm

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint

eslint --fix option is not working when i run it through npm. Here is my **package.json** scripts

```
"scripts":            
{
    "start": "nodemon ./server.js --exec babel-node",          
    "lint": "eslint ./data/* --format html  --output-file ./finalresult.html --fix ; exit 0"
}
```

when I run it using command **npm run lint** report is generating but without fixing. But if I am running the same command

> **eslint ./data/* --format html  --output-file ./finalresult.html --fix**

from console it is generating report after fix.Why is it so? Am I doing anything wrong? Can Anyone please help me

Comment: is the version of eslint in your node modules same as it is globally?
Or are you sure the errors are fix-able?

Comment: Hi @tbking you were spot on. In my package .json i changed the command to /usr/local/bin/eslint ./data/* --format html  --output-file ./finalresult.html --fix and now it works perfectly fine with npm run lint. Thanks a lot

Comment: The reason was version mismatch

Comment: Cool. It happens to all of us. I'll just write it as an answer so that other people can find it easily

Comment: Anyone else running into this may also want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/74817581/5602521 which ended up being my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the version of the `eslint` in your local and global node_modules.

When we run from command line, the global eslint executes while npm uses the one in local node_modules.